# Regex matching human readable number

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm having some trouble with a regex I'm writing for one of the codewars Katas (https://www.codewars.com/kata/parseint-reloaded/train/ruby) and I was hoping I could be pointed in the right direction here. I have need of a regex that can match an english , human readable number string, anywhere from 1 to 999. For example: "one", "three hundred two", "five hundred ninety seven", etc.

When I match with the regex, I'd like the matches to appear in consistent backtreference locations. What I have written so far more or less works in most cases but the backreferences are all over the place. Sometimes when I match "hundred". it goes in to $3, other times in $6, and it's making the logic to pull out the numbers convoluted. Other times the same string appears twice. Is there any way to salvage this and make it better, or should I bite the bullet and write multiple regexes for the different cases?

## regex_test.rb

```
regex = "^((.+?)( hundred)? )?((.+)[ -])?(.+?)$"

test_cases = [
  'seven hundred ninety six',
  'six hundred twenty-two',
  'one hundred',
  'two hundred one',
  'sixty six',
  'one',
  'sixty'
]

test_cases.each do |test_case|
  puts test_case.match(regex).to_a.inspect
end
```

## Output:

```
["seven hundred ninety six", "seven hundred ", "seven", " hundred", "ninety ", "ninety", "six"]
["six hundred twenty-two", "six hundred ", "six", " hundred", "twenty-", "twenty", "two"]
["one hundred", "one ", "one", nil, nil, nil, "hundred"]
["two hundred one", "two hundred ", "two", " hundred", nil, nil, "one"]
["sixty six", "sixty ", "sixty", nil, nil, nil, "six"]
["one", nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, "one"]
["sixty", nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, "sixty"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, construct hashes that will be used to convert strings to integers, and use the keys of those hashes to define words that may appear in the string for insertion in the regular expression.

```
units_to_digit = %w| one two three four five six seven eight nine |.
  zip((1..9).to_a).to_h
  #=> {"one"=>1, "two"=>2, "three"=>3, "four"=>4, "five"=>5, "six"=>6, "seven"=>7,
  #    "eight"=>8, "nine"=>9}
units = units_to_digit.keys.join('|')
  #=> "one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine"

tens_to_digit = %w| twenty thirty forty fifty sixty seventy eighty ninety |.
  zip((2..9).to_a).to_h
  #=> {"twenty"=>2, "thirty"=>3, "forty"=>4, "fifty"=>5, "sixty"=>6, "seventy"=>7,
  #    "eighty"=>8, "ninety"=>9}
tens = tens_to_digit.keys.join('|')
  #=> "twenty|thirty|forty|fifty|sixty|seventy|eighty|ninety"

teens_to_digit =
  %w| ten eleven twelve thirteen fourteen fifteen sixteen seventeen eighteen nineteen |.
  zip((10..19).to_a).to_h
  #=> {"ten"=>10, "eleven"=>11, "twelve"=>12, "thirteen"=>13, "fourteen"=>14,
  #    "fifteen"=>15, "sixteen"=>16, "seventeen"=>17, "eighteen"=>18, "nineteen"=>19}
teens = teens_to_digit.keys.join('|')
  #=>  "ten|eleven|twelve|thirteen|fourteen|fifteen|sixteen|seventeen|eighteen|nineteen"
```

(One could alternatively write `units = Regexp.union(units_to_digit.keys)` and similar for `tens` and `teens`. See [Regexp::union](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Regexp.html#method-c-union).)

Next, construct a regular expression using named capture groups. (I've used free-spacing mode for documentation purpose. The characters classes containing a single space (`[ ]`) can each be replaced by a space if free-spacing mode is not used.)

```
regex = /
        \A                            # match beginning of string
        (?:                           # begin a non-capture group
          (?<nbr_hundreds>#{units})   # match nbr of hundreds, named 'nbr_hundreds'
          [ ]hundred                  # match ' hundred'        
        )?                            # close non-capture group and make optional 
        [ ]?                          # optionally match a space
        (?:                           # begin non-capture group
          (?:                         # begin a non-capture group 
            (?<tens>#{tens})          # match 'twenty' to 'ninety', named 'tens'
            (?:                       # begin non-capture group
              [ -]                    # match a space or hyphen
              (?<tens_units>#{units}) # match units, named 'tens_units'
            )?                        # close non-capture group and make optional
          )                           # close non-capture group
          |                           # or
          (?<units>#{units})          # match '1-9', named 'units'
          |                           # or
          (?<teens>#{teens})          # match 'ten', 'eleven',...'nineteen'
        )?                            # close non-capture group and make optional
        \z                            # match end of string
        /x                            # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

```
  #=>   /
  #     \A
  #     (?:
  #       (?<nbr_hundreds>one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine)
  #       [ ]hundred
  #     )?
  #     [ ]?
  #     (?:
  #       (?: 
  #         (?<tens>twenty|thirty|forty|fifty|sixty|seventy|eighty|ninety)
  #         (?:
  #           [ -]
  #           (?<tens_units>one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine)
  #         )?
  #       )
  #       |
  #       (?<units>one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine)
  #       |
  #       (?<teens>ten|eleven|twelve|thirteen|fourteen|fifteen|sixteen|seventeen|eighteen|nineteen)
  #     )?
  #     \z
  #     /x
```

`str.match(regex)` will return a `MatchData` object `m`. The values of the capture groups will be `m[:nbr_hundreds]`, `m[:tens]`, `m[:tens_units]`, `m[:units]` and `m[:teens]`. Each will equal `nil` when there is no match. (For example, `m[:nbr_hundreds]` will equal `nil` when `str = "one"`.) It is convenient to simply treat these nils as zeros. An easy way of doing that is to add a key-value pair `nil=>0` to each of the hashes `units_to_digit`, `tens_to_digit` and `teens_to_digit`:

```
units_to_digit[nil] = 0
tens_to_digit[nil] = 0
teens_to_digit[nil] = 0
```

Now construct a method that converts a `MatchData` object to an integer.

```
def match_data_to_integer(units_to_digit, tens_to_digit, teens_to_digit, m)
  100 * units_to_digit[m[:nbr_hundreds]] +
  10  * tens_to_digit[m[:tens]] +
  teens_to_digit[m[:teens]] +
  units_to_digit[m[:tens_units]] +
  units_to_digit[m[:units]]
end
```

Let's now test this against some strings.

```
test_cases = [
  'seven hundred ninety six',
  'six hundred twenty-two',
  'one hundred',
  'two hundred one',
  'sixty six',
  'one',
  'sixty'
]

test_cases.each do |test_case|
  m = test_case.match(regex)
  n = match_data_to_integer(units_to_digit, tens_to_digit, teens_to_digit, m)
  puts "#{test_case} -> #{n}"
end
```

prints

```
seven hundred ninety six -> 796
six hundred twenty-two -> 622
one hundred -> 100
two hundred one -> 201
sixty six -> 66
one -> 1
sixty -> 60
```

Comment: This is a great answer. I had no idea you could name your capture groups, nor that you could omit them from appearing in the backreferences. Thanks so much, I feel like I leveled up my regexes because of you!